# Is on Python 3 any library to relaunch the script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some script in Python, which does some work. I want to re-run this script automatically. Also, I want to relaunch it on any crashes/freezes.
I can do something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        main()
    except Exception:
        os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

But, for unknown reason, this still crashes or freezes one time in few days. So I see crash, write "Python main.py" in cmd and it started, so I don't know why os.execv don't do this work by self. I guess it's because this code is part of this app. So, I prefer some script/app, which will control relaunch in external way. I hope it will be more stable.

So this script should work in this way:

1. Start any script
2. Check that process of this script is working, for example check some file time change and control it by process name|ID|etc.
3. When it dissapears from process list, launch it again
4. When file changed more than 5 minutes ago, stop process, wait few sec, launch it again.
5. In general: be cross-platform (Linux/Windows)
6. *not important* log all crashes.

I can do this by self (right now working on it), but I'm pretty sure something like this must already be done by somebody, I just can't find it in Google\Github.

UPDATE: added code from the @hansaplast answer to GitHub. Also added some changes to it: [relauncher](https://github.com/Swich1987/relauncher). Feel free to copy/use it.

Comment: Search for "watchdog" (with relevant modifiers). Handling process termination is easier than dealing with 'a process that randomly "hung"'.

Comment: @user2864740, I looked at watchdog, looks like it helps to keep monitoring changes in file system. It will help, thanks, but it didn't resolve the overall problem. I still need to code all other parts. And I can't believe, that nobody hadn't done this before.

Comment: Oh, I see. The 'watchdog' Python package is not very relevant :( That's unfortunate naming. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer , https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-watchdog/ etc.

Comment: @user2864740, the watchdog on systutorials.com  shut down the entire system and is not cross-platform. (Only on Linux). So I can't use it. On wiki is only general information of how this work. Unfortunately, it's not what I search.

Comment: In GNU/Linux, you can leverage the system init to restart your process on certain conditions e.g. see `Restart` statement of `systemd`.

Comment: As for "why", it seems pretty obvious that an exception is not the problem. A freeze could mean that Python stopped executing altogether, or that it is stuck in a loop.

Comment: @heemayl, thanks, I need a cross-platform solution. And, as I know, it can be done with just pure Python.

Comment: @tripleee, last time my script froze in case of freezing Selenium Webdriver, probably in case of one of Chrome extension (but I need to use it). Any settings(timeout, etc...) on Selenium didn't help. So it's not loop and also not Python fault. I think it's possible to meet many other situations when just usual "kill" and "restart" is all that you need to keep the script working.

Comment: If you are certain that your script will never crash then controlling it entirely from Python is feasible. But look at what you are struggling with right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it needs to work both in windows and on linux I don't know a way to do that with standard tools, so here's a DIY solution:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import os
import time

# change into scripts directory
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

while True:
    p = Popen(['python', 'my_script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
    time.sleep(20) # give the program some time to write into logfile
    while True:
        if p.poll() != None:
            print('crashed or regularly terminated')
            break
        file_age_in_s = time.time() - os.path.getmtime('output.log')
        if file_age_in_s > 60:
            print('frozen, killing process')
            p.kill()
            break
        time.sleep(1)

    print('restarting..')
```

Explanation:

- `time.sleep(20)`: give script 20 seconds to write into the log file
- `poll()`: regularly check if script died (either crashed or regularly terminated, you can check the return value of poll() to differentiate that)
- `getmtime()`: regularly check `output.log` and check if that was changed the past 60 seconds
- `time.sleep(1)`: between every check wait for `1s` as otherwise it would eat up too many system resources

The script assumes that the check-script and the run-script are in the same directory. If that is not the case, change the lines beneath "change into scripts directory"

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will try it for some time and look, how it will work.

Comment: Not taking anything away, but `poll()`-ing is costly. Good to see at least some added `time.sleep`.

Comment: Is it costly? Thought this was just a syscall? Is there a cheaper way to check if the process is still alive?

Comment: @hansaplast, ok, I found a problem here: if it freezes few times, you don't kill it, so you will have a bunch of freezes processes in the system, right? So you need to add p.kill() when "frozen", right?

Comment: @VladimirOprya good catch. I missed this bit. I added a `p.kill()` to my answer

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) daemon, but it has two issues here:

1. It is only for unix systems
2. It restarts app only on crashes, not freezes.

But it has simple XML-RPC API, so It makes your job to write an freeze-watchdog app simplier. You could just start your process under supervisor and restart it via supervisor API when you see it freezes.

You could install it via *apt install supervisor* on ubuntu and write config like this:

```
[program:main]
user=vladimir
command=python3 /var/local/main/main.py
process_name=%(program_name)s
directory=/var/local/main
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Comment: all are nice, thanks, but cross-platform is one of the main requirements. I can, but don't want to make 2 scripts for Linux and Windows separated.